# Get all registered listeners to an ObservableValue

Tags: javafx

How to get all listeners to an observable value? I could extend the class and override `addListener` and `removeListener` methods to store them in a set. But the set should already be stored somehow inside observable value. How could I get that set?

Comment: The methods are declared in the `ObservableValue` interface that does not provide any method to find the listeners added (it doesn't even return a boolean telling you whether the you actually removed a certain observer). I'm pretty sure this is done on purpose (information hiding; if you could get a `Set` of all listeners, you could also remove them...). Perhaps you're lucky and the property classes extend `XYZPropertyBase` and you could use reflection to force access to the listeners, but this way you're doing something that the API is not meant to do...

Answer (score 1):

I find a way around it, you can't get direct access to the Listeners list but if you use a debugger(I use IntelliJ) you can see it if you look inside your ObservableProprty like this:(I hope this is clear enough)
[image]

another way:(You're a smart guy, you'll know how to fit into your case)

```
    //SimpleFloatProperty we want to find its Listeners
    FloatPropertyBase f=ampPS.currentProperty();
    Object value;
    ChangeListener[] list;
    ChangeListener changeListener=null;
    Field field = null;
    try {
        field = FloatPropertyBase.class.getDeclaredField("helper");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        value = field.get(f);
        try {
            field = value.getClass().getDeclaredField("listener");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            changeListener =(WeakChangeListener)field.get(value);
        }catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            field = value.getClass().getDeclaredField("changeListeners");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            list =(ChangeListener[])field.get(value);
        }catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the result:
[image]

(Notice the difference between 1 listener or more than 1)

I I'm adding Example for several types of values

```
public static ChangeListener[] getChangeListeners(ObservableValue observableValue){

    Object value;
    ChangeListener[] list=null;
    ChangeListener changeListener=null;
    Field field = null;

    try {
        if(observableValue instanceof SimpleFloatProperty ){
            field = FloatPropertyBase.class.getDeclaredField("helper");
        }
        else if(observableValue instanceof SimpleBooleanProperty ){
            field = BooleanPropertyBase.class.getDeclaredField("helper");
        }
        else if(observableValue instanceof SimpleIntegerProperty ){
            field = IntegerPropertyBase.class.getDeclaredField("helper");
        }
        field.setAccessible(true);
        value = field.get(observableValue);
        try {
            field = value.getClass().getDeclaredField("listener");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            changeListener =(ChangeListener)field.get(value);
        }catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            field = value.getClass().getDeclaredField("changeListeners");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            list =(ChangeListener[])field.get(value);
        }catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(list!=null){
        return list;
    }
    else {
        ChangeListener[] changeListeners = new  ChangeListener[1];
        changeListeners[0]=changeListener;
        return changeListeners;
    }
}
```

and I call it:

```
    SimpleBooleanProperty booleanProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);
    SimpleFloatProperty simpleFloatProperty = new SimpleFloatProperty(0);
    SimpleIntegerProperty simpleIntegerProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
    booleanProperty.addListener(changeListener);
    simpleFloatProperty.addListener(changeListener);
    simpleIntegerProperty.addListener(changeListener);
    simpleIntegerProperty.addListener(changeListener);
    System.out.println(getChangeListeners(booleanProperty).length);
    System.out.println(getChangeListeners(simpleFloatProperty).length);
    System.out.println(getChangeListeners(simpleIntegerProperty).length);
```

the result: [image]

so I do get warnings, but the job is done!

Comment: long awaited java 9 release with its jigsaw made access to javafx internals problematic

Comment: field = value.getClass().getDeclaredField("listener");
Is can help to work around the problem :) i can't import it, but I can uses getClass after I get object of it(I use java 9 with this code)

Comment: I edited my answer to add more ObservableValues, it not can work directly with ObservableValue interface but you can add values by your needs...

Comment: @ayvango wondering why you want to access the listeners ... you shouldn't care about them ;)

Comment: for me, it helps to identify a problem of not GC events because of a forgotten pointer or worse a Stage that hide and its pointer set to null  but its registers events still occurred(although I used weak listeners)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `ObservableValue.removeListener` states:

> If the given listener has not been previously registered (i.e. it was never added) then this method call is a no-op.

This leaves a few options if reflection is to be avoided.

First, call `removeListener` before adding the listener, such as:

```
final var property = someProperty();
final var listener = getListener();
property.removeListener( listener );
property.addListener( listener );
```

This technique is equivalent to using a `Set`, provided `getListener()` always returns the same object reference. (This *may* also work if different object references of the same class override `equals` to return `true`, but you'd have to double-check.)

The downside is having to keep a reference to the listener that was added, which could require a new class, but will at least require a new instance variable.

Second, keep a map of registered listeners, something to the effect of:

```
final HashMap<ObservableValue<?>, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
final var property = someProperty();
final var listener = getListener();
map.computeIfAbsent( property, p -> {
  property.addListener( listener );
  return property;
});
```

Although the question is looking for the list of listeners, I suspect the intent of the question is to avoid adding duplicate listeners, which is a common scenario.

Comment: while possible, doing whatever to keep a storage of added (by code that the custom app only! - all the others are not accessible) listeners is obsoleting each and every single attempt of the system to keep them as unobstrusive as possible (f.i. by removing them if elligible for gc - with many holes, concededly ;) The _real_ problem is to closely look at the reasons for wanting access to listeners added by unaccessible parties .. and not do it :)