# JavaFX check if a Node property is being listened

Tags: java, javafx, listener

I have a method that adds a listener to a certain Node property, during the execution, this method might be called more than one time, and this will add another (but same) listener to that Node property, so I tried to remove the listener before adding another one to avoid duplicates like that :

```
myProperty.removeListener(this::method);
myProperty.addListener(this::method);
```

This looks correct, but the problem here is that, before removing, I must check that the property currently don't have a listener, something like that :

```
if(myProperty.hasListener(this::method)) //
```

But this doesn't seem to exist, then how to check if a Node property is being listened or no?

Thank you.

**[EDIT : SOLVED]**

the `removeListener(ChangeListener)` method will not cause an error even if the listener doesn't exist.

Comment: hmm .. not entirely certain that the first will do what you want - did you test it? Anyway, no there is no api to check for registered listeners, you'll have to implement it yourself (by a flag, reference to the listener, whatever)

Comment: don't quite understand _why_ you are adding the same listener multiple times .. sounds like suboptimal logic/setup

Comment: you may want to look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162216/get-all-regestired-listeners-to-an-observable-value/48325077#48325077

Comment: @kleopatra, to make it simple, I have many textareas in different tabs and a variable containing the current textArea, this variable is changing according to the selected textArea that's why I have to add a listener multiple times. but anyway, the firsts code I wrote is working fine, I was afraid the remove method to cause an error, but it seems to work even if there is no listener at all.
So I guess the problem is solved :)

Comment: don't know what you mean be _working_ .. but removing the listener like in your first snippet _does not_ remove it, it's still registered and does whatever it is meant to do ;) Again: change your application design such that you can keep track of which property you are listening to and add/remove a listener (that's stored in a field vs. a method handle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun(not recommended):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {

            }
        };
        SimpleBooleanProperty simpleBooleanProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        System.out.println(hasListener(simpleBooleanProperty,changeListener));
        simpleBooleanProperty.addListener(changeListener);
        System.out.println(hasListener(simpleBooleanProperty,changeListener));
        simpleBooleanProperty.removeListener(changeListener);
        System.out.println(hasListener(simpleBooleanProperty,changeListener));
    }

    public static boolean hasListener(ObservableValue observableValue, ChangeListener listener){

        Object value;
        ChangeListener[] list=null;
        ChangeListener changeListener=null;
        Field field = null;

        try {
            if(observableValue instanceof SimpleFloatProperty){
                field = FloatPropertyBase.class.getDeclaredField("helper");
            }
            else if(observableValue instanceof SimpleBooleanProperty){
                field = BooleanPropertyBase.class.getDeclaredField("helper");
            }
            else if(observableValue instanceof SimpleIntegerProperty){
                field = IntegerPropertyBase.class.getDeclaredField("helper");
            }
            field.setAccessible(true);
            value = field.get(observableValue);
            try {
                if(value==null){
                    return false;
                }
                field = value.getClass().getDeclaredField("listener");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                changeListener =(ChangeListener)field.get(value);
            }catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                field = value.getClass().getDeclaredField("changeListeners");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                list =(ChangeListener[])field.get(value);
            }catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(list!=null){
            for (ChangeListener c:list) {
                if(c==listener){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return changeListener==listener;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

output:

```
false
true
false
```

More rational method: use a map or flag.

by the way:

you can remove also if there is no listener at all so you don't have to check before you remove
[image]

Comment: I just noticed what you said about the listener removal, I was afraid it causes an error, but guess I was wrong, also thanks for the code, it's clever!

Comment: quite a lot of dirt for working around a (most probably) broken application design ;) But then ..  what we do for fun <g>